# FontForge - Remove anti-aliasing/subpixel rendering when generating TTF font

Tags: fonts, antialiasing, fontforge

I have a font that I'm cleaning up in FontForge to fix issues with points being too far from the main shape, causing characters to render with odd slants at certain font sizes. I did this in FontForge by correcting every point's position then removing all the overlaps with the Element > Overlap > Remove Overlap feature on every character. Everything looks far better now, and in GIMP it renders well.

The issue is when I generate the font, there's some noticeable anti-aliasing going on, and it's very apparent when I view the font at 10px in Windows. The previous version of the font didn't have this anti-aliasing before I edited it. I've searched around all over and can't find where to disable anti-aliasing in FontForge when generating the font. Here are my export settings:

- TrueType, No Bitmap Fonts
- In the "Options" dialog, only the following are selected:

  - TrueType Hints
  - PS Glyph Names
  - Windows-compatible 'kern'

To note, I'm modifying the font in FontForge on Linux. So my question is: how can I remove anti-aliasing when exporting the font? Which settings should I be looking for?

I appreciate any advice in getting this fixed!

EDIT: Here's an image showing the issue on the "S" character. The font size is the same.

[image]

Comment: there is no "anti-aliassing" in fonts, because font glyphs are inherently "gridless" graphics, like all vector graphics. There is hinting, and there are bitmap strikes for use at low point sizes, but that's it. Run the previous and new version through [TTX](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) and compare the two. For example: did you accidentally strip out the `fpgm` table?

Comment: The `fpgm` table is present in both versions as well as the instructions for each character. I'm not familiar with the internals of fonts, so I'm not sure what else to look out for. I've linked an image in the main post showing the issue; hopefully this helps give more leads.

Comment: Honestly that looks like the EBDT table went missing or something. The character on the left is almost guaranteed a bitmap strike for point size 15. You may also want to ask this over on https://typedrawers.com (probably in the font technology category), which is the more authoritative place to ask questions when it comes specifically to opentype font engineering and internals.

Comment: In terms of TTX debugging, check to see if the console output for the table names is the same, before comparing the actual resultant XML. If there are tables in one that aren't in the other, that's a good place to start looking.